# newcommand for double underscores without space with listing package

Tags: symbols, underscore

I know, the similar questions have already asked and (most correctly) answered too. But I am getting stuck while writing `__log` or `__inti__` in the block diagram or in text. The simplest solution already exist i.e. to define `\newcommand{\twound}{\rule{2\dunder}{0.4pt}}` and use in text works great. But when I use `listing package`, it is just ignored by the tex compiler. The another solution mentioned to use `inline` command with `listing` won't actually worked for me. I defined the said command sequence in my project's class file. But the

```
\newcommand\li{%
    \lstinline[basicstyle = \verbfont\raggedright]}
```

suppresses the further commands. Maybe the `\lstinline` not completing. Any help please?

Comment: Do you want that *all* your underscores in a listing are double length?

Comment: No. Not the every _underscore_ . But only at specific instances within text and in the flow diagram's comment blocks. For flow diagram I am using `tikz` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use `\lstline` then one way to do this is via a `literal` substitution pattern.

```
literal={x}{y}n
```

replaces `x` by `y` and makes it take up the space of `n` characters.  Here you can write

```
literal={__}{\twound}2
```

to replace `__` by the `\twound` symbol and regard it as two characters width in the output.

[image: Sample output]

Replace the `2` by `1` if you want the double underline to be closer to the symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newlength\dunder
\settowidth\dunder{\_}
\newcommand{\twound}{\rule{2\dunder}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

\lstinline[literate={__}{\twound}2]{__inti__}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use this repeatedly in your document you may prefer to write

```
\lstset{literate={__}{\twound}2}
```

in the preamble and then just use

```
\lstinline{__inti__}
```

in the body of the document.